# PHP exec function : redirect to dev/null to exit script ( Ratchet loop )

Tags: php, exec, ratchet

I'm using ratchet to build a telnet/php program.

I need to be able to check if the server loop is running and if not launch it via a php exec command, then send the info that the loop is started to the client.

I have the following lines :

```
$file = "php " . ABS_PATH . "inc/lib/telnet/telnet_server.php > /dev/null &";
exec($file);

print "done";
```

Unfortunately, the script seems to hang in the exec part so I cannot send the info to the client.

I'm working locally in an EasyPHP environment so I need to be able to test the result first under Windows, then on a Linux webserver.

Any help appreciated...

Thx in advance !

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue a while back and wrote a neat little function that works on windows and linux to run a process in the background

```
function execInBackground($cmd) {
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));
    }
    else {
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");
    }
}
```

Usage is quite simple, in your case it would be `execInBackground("php " . ABS_PATH . "inc/lib/telnet/telnet_server.php");`

Answer (score 0):

[exec](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) is a blocking command since it waits for the output.
If you want to start a process / daemon, you should look at [popen](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) or [proc_open](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php).

Since you probably want to send data to the process, you'll need the latter.

You can use [proc_get_status](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-get-status.php) to retrieve and store the PID (process id) so you can check later whether the process is already running.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there seems to be a valid answer in the comments part here : [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Hope this helps someone^^